# How do you get a documentSnapshot from firestore over a cloud function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

a bit of intro first, I need to get the documentSnapshot and not only the data of a record which is in Firestore because I have pagination in my app, and to do that, when you query you need to send the last documentSnapshot from where your query will send the 10 next records.

So, this worked fine with the SDK, but I want to implement Cloud Functions now, and when I try to respond with a documentSnapshot from the cloud function I am not able to get the documentSnapshot in Flutter.

This is the portion of code where the issue is:

```
final function = _cloudFunctions.getHttpsCallable(
  functionName: 'createRecord',
);
try {
  final response = await function.call(data);
  final DocumentSnapshot doc = response.data;
  return doc;
} catch (e) {
  print(e)
  return null;
}
```

Whith this code I get the error: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot'

Is there a workaround or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from a callable Cloud Function is not going to be a strongly typed [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html).  That's what the error message is trying to tell you.  You're getting a map type object, and you have to deal with that object as such.  You can't just force it to be a DocumentSnapshot.

If you're using your callable function as a tool for pagination, you won't be able to pass DocumentSnapshot objects back and forth between the client and function.  You're going to have to pass the function enough information to paginate without providing a DocumentSnapshot.

A DocumentSnapshot is not actually required to paginate - what you do need is enough information to tell the query to pick up where it left off, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#add_a_simple_cursor_to_a_query).  This involves using startAt or startAfter using information from the last document seen.

Comment: Doug, thanks for answering. I understand that it's impossible to get the DocumentSnapshot type on the response itself, but I thought that it could be a way to "construct" it from the object received as response.
Now with respect to using startAt/startAfter, I discarded it because this method isn't completely accurate. I sort the records by date and description but these two fields can be repeated, therefore I will receive an erroneous response when I make the call.

Comment: If a date can be repeated, you can use the document ID as a tie-breaker.  Internally, Firestore always uses an additional sort on document ID in order to create a deterministic sort order.  You can simply do this yourself in order to paginate in the same way the Firestore SDK would if you provided it with a DocumentSnapshot.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, I can solve this by adding to the query an **orderBy(documentID)** and **startAfter()** with the documentID of the last seen document. The only thing remaining is how to put the documentID in orderBy? since it is not a "data" field. I was just googling but I didn't find the way to do it in Dart.

Comment: In initially answered you here incorrectly and deleted the comments, but yes, you should be able to add another `orderby(FieldValue.documentId())` (or whatever equivalent flutter), and provide both the time and document ID using the startAt that takes multiple parameters.

Comment: I have come to this `.orderBy(FieldPath.documentId)` in Dart. But it says that the query requires an index and when I click on the link to make that index it shows that I'm trying to make the index with date only (the other orderBy) therefore it doesn't let me create the index because it says that single field index aren't necessary. So close yet so far haha.

Comment: This happens when using `orderBy('date', descending: true)`. Without the descending order it works as intended. But I need the descending order.

Comment: I finally got it, I just used both orderBys with "descending: true". Thanks for your help Doug.